# Select Multiple Conditions - 2 DataFrames - Create New Column

Tags: python, pandas, select

I have 2 DataFrames:

DF1 - Master List

```
ID     Item
100    Wood
101    Steel
102    Brick
103    Soil
```

DF2

```
ID    
100    
103
```

I want my final DataFrame to look like this:

```
ID     Item / ID
100    100 - Wood
103    103 - Soil
```

The issue I'm having is DF2 doesn't have the Item Column.

I could manually do it by `np.select(conditions, choices, default='N/A')` but the full dataset is huge and would take a lot of time.

I also tried an `np.select` from the 2 different datasets, citing the columns but got a `Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects.` error.

Is there a way to pull the relevant information from `Item` so I can join the strings values from `ID` to create `Item / ID`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dff = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'right', on = 'ID')
dff['Item / ID'] = dff['ID'].astype(str) + ' - ' + dff['Item']
dff.drop('Item', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(dff)
```

output:

```
    ID   Item / ID
0  100  100 - Wood
1  103  103 - Soil
```